I want to know how to utilise angular material in Angular 17
I want to know how to utilise angular material in Angular 17 because in the previous version, I made a material.module.ts and import as necessary ,
nevertheless, how to use angular 17 , i want to create a seprate file and import file
I have a standalone component
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
 import { genericMessage } from '@shared/generic/genericMessage.enum';
 import { MatTabsModule } from "@angular/material/tabs";
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatIconModule } from "@angular/material/icon";
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-add-department',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatTableModule,
    MatSortModule,
    NgClass,  
    FeatherIconsComponent,      
    MatPaginatorModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgFor,NgIf,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,       
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    
  ],
  templateUrl: './add-department.component.html',
  styleUrl: './add-department.component.scss'
})
export class AddDepartmentComponent extends UnsubscribeOnDestroyAdapter
implements OnInit {
}

previous angular version i have create a material.module.ts
and import where needed
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { MatTabsModule } from "@angular/material/tabs";
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatIconModule } from "@angular/material/icon";
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { MatMenuTrigger, MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatOptionModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
        MatTabsModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,       
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatOptionModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,

      
    ],
    exports: [
        MatTabsModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatOptionModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,

    ]
})

export class MaterialModule { }


The Angular documentation describes how to do this. You do not need a file with all the Material modules. But instead you can import de module you need.
https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#using-existing-ngmodules-in-a-standalone-component
